# Wait and send batch of commands on save

Tags: c#, cqrs

I have a WPF application connected to a remote backend: the user can edit many different elements on the GUI but decide to save or discard only on application closing.
The GUI support undo/redo.

I already track every edit and on save generate the necessary commands to perform edits on backend: my commands is something like:

```
public class ChangeDescriptionOfTypeAObject
{
  public string OldValue{ get; set; }      
  public string NewValue{ get; set; }
  public string ObjectID{ get; set; }
}
```

This works in the current app but i'm thinking about command failure if another user change the same property in the meantime. Probably I have to send a message to user that "Description changes on object ObjectID cannot be applied: the current value is xxx" and apply all others changes.

Is this a correct approach?
How can I be sure that a command can be applied with success in an eventually consistent process if the read model that I use to check for "CurrentValue==OldValue" is being updated from another consumer?

Comment: I think that depends - IMO the best aproach is to make the *events* and *commands* smaller than what you did and bring some kind of concurrency check with them (usually just a version-number) - then before updates you can requerry the current state again and if all else fails the backend will throw you an concurrency check - I don't think that you can really avoid this without somekind of lock

Comment: To make this a bit more clear: the backend has to check for consistency! (The front-end can check too but the backend must have the last say)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that you need to well understand and apply [optimistic concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz(v=vs.110).aspx), which is really recommanded when you use eventual consistency.

And for that Carsten König is right, you need to track by the way you want your object change to know if someone else change it when you want to save it in the backend. This can be done with a version number, MSDN propose to use a TimeStamp.

Whatever, the point is that you need to check that only one user change your object when you save it, or at least that the changes apply to your object have no conflicts with other changes. Otherwise you need to raise error and inform the user that the changes cannot be saved (or provide some kind of merge process).

> the user can edit many different elements on the GUI but decide to
>   save or discard only on application closing

The problem with this approach is that it is not really compliant with optimistic concurrency, because the longer it takes to modify your object, the most chance you have to create a conflict with another user change. The feature "manage undo/redo" is not a reason IMHO to not inform the server of the changes asap, unless you have some constraints for the communication with your server.

I see three solutions depending of your context:

- If it is acceptable for the domain, you can use pessimistic concurrency (ie lock the data manage in your UI) as long as the user do not close your application (obviously it is a really not scalable solution), and keep your current undo/redo management.
- Otherwise, if you need to be scalable, use optimistic concurrency, thus prefer not to send all data in the end, but after each change to your model (and manage the undo/redo process at server side)
- Or keep you current implementation, add optimistic concurrency and provide some merge solution for your users if multi modification of the same object often happen

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand but for the command processing side: I have to recreate my object from saved events that can be missing latest events in process, or I miss some knownledge?

Comment: I'am sorry I do not understand what you mean? Your objects are created during the query (when you create your UI probably). So when you send a command to update these objects, you need to check that they were not modified somewhere else.